# How to pass Lists as arguments using for loop in a function?

Tags: python, list, arguments

```
def conversion(putlist):
  if(len(putlist)>len(set(putlist))):
      putlist = set(putlist)
      putlist = list(putlist)
      print("{}have duplicates".format(putlist))
  else:
      putlist = set(putlist)
      putlist = list(putlist)
      print(putlist)

for i in range[brent, camden, redbridge, southwark]:  
     conversion(i)
```

**error**
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ySB6.png)

**Neglect the indentation**
*I want to pass 4 lists as arguments to function conversion() with the help of for loop so I ain't have to pass the arguments 4 times.*

Answer (score 3):

Replace:

```
for i in range[brent, camden, redbridge, southwark]:  <-------getting error
```

with

```
for i in [brent, camden, redbridge, southwark]:
```

Comment: it is not working getting errorTypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-105-eb35d715506d> in <module>
     14 
     15 for i in [brent, camden, redbridge, southwark]:
---> 16     conversion(i)
     17 

<ipython-input-105-eb35d715506d> in conversion(putlist)
      9     else:
     10         putlist = set(putlist)
---> 11         putlist = list(putlist)
     12         print(putlist)
     13 

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: @MoranLeven care to share the error message?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp

`range` - generator, this function makes a list for you

You are not needed in this function if you already have a list

wiki page about generator: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

```
for i in [brent, camden, redbridge, southwark]:
    conversion(*i)
```